# PHP file upload path getting added in database but not beside logged in users's row

Tags: php, mysql, database, file-upload

In the table 'cvupldr` file is getting added for user 'bbn' and path is shown in 'file' row. But instead of showing the the path beside bbn's row a new row is getting created.

```
<?php $user=$_SESSION['username'];$resum=mysql_query("select file from cvupldr where username='$user'");while($row=mysql_fetch_array($resum)){ echo "<a href='uploads/".$row[0]."'>".$row[0]."</a>"; }?>
```

This is the database pic.

[image]

Comment: Could you add the code to the question instead of linking to it? Same for the image

Comment: Embedded linked pictures

Answer (score 0):

> But instead of showing the the path beside bbn's row a new row is getting created.

That's because instead of updating the row, you're inserting a new row to the table. You SQL query should be like this:

```
$sql = "UPDATE cvupldr SET file='{$file_name}' WHERE username='{$user}'";
```

Comment: now file is getting added in 'uploads' folder but not getting displayed in <td> of table where i want to display it. Could you please help? This is the code - 
<?php $user=$_SESSION['username'];$resum=mysql_query("select file from cvupldr where username='$user'");while($row=mysql_fetch_array($resum)){ echo "<a href='uploads/".$row[0]."'>".$row[0]."</a>"; }?>

Comment: @AtitD.Salvi Your code here in the comment is unreadable. Please update your question.

Comment: <?php $user=$_SESSION['username'];
$resum=mysql_query("select file from cvupldr where username='$user'");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($resum)){ echo "<a href='uploads/".$row[0]."'>".$row[0]."</a>"; }?>

Comment: Edited the code abovein the main question, could you please help now? @Rajdeep Paul

Comment: @AtitD.Salvi so you want to display all the images of a particular user, right?

Comment: User uploads a file which is getting stored in 'uploads' folder. Then that file is being displayed in his profile. And for displaying, the code above in the post is used but still file is not getting displayed. @Rajdeep Paul

Comment: @AtitD.Salvi [Here's the solution](http://pastebin.com/p6ujEtEN). **Warning:** `mysql_` extensions were deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and were  completely removed in PHP 7.0.0, use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead.

Comment: Could you please guide me how to do it because I'm not familiar with it! @Rajdeep Paul

Comment: @AtitD.Salvi how to do what? Replace your code with the one I gave you, that's it.

Comment: I'm not getting it. Leave it!

Comment: @AtitD.Salvi may I know what you're not getting?

Comment: @AtitD.Salvi  You misinterpreted it. I didn't ask you to use `mysqli` or `PDO` in your code. What I meant is, from now on you should start using `mysqli` or `PDO` because it prevents your code from any kind of SQL injection. For your problem, just replace your code with the one I gave in pastebin.